# concat in koalas dataframe fails with error "Job aborted due to stage failure"

Tags: python, pandas, databricks, spark-koalas

I am running pyspark notebook in Azure databricks environment and auto scaling cluster(2 to 32).
I have 2 dataframes df1 and df2 and concatenating using the below code using Pandas.

df1 -> 9 columns and around 11 million records
df2-> exactly similar schema as df1, 13 million records
I am concatenating using  pd.concat(df1,df2,IgnoreIndex=True) and is working fine.
Now in order to distribute, I am converting Pandas into Koalas, I converted df1 and df2 to Koalas dataframe. But when I concatenate using ks.concat(df1,df2,IgnoreIndex=True),it always gives the below error.

*Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 5 in stage 226.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 5.3 in stage 226.0 (TID 17592) (10.54.144.21 executor 125): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Checkpoint block rdd_593_5 not found! Either the executor that originally checkpointed this partition is no longer alive, or the original RDD is unpersisted. If this problem persists, you may consider using `rdd.checkpoint()` instead, which is slower than local checkpointing but more fault-tolerant*

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Nikesh

Comment: Can you elaborate about what you mean by `In order to distribute`?

Comment: My understanding is that Pandas will be utilizing only on the driver node , documentation  of Koalas says, it uses distributed computing and hence used all the worker nodes or executors.

Comment: Have you tried using `Pandas API on Spark` or directly using Spark dataframe?